# member variable as pointer to template type c++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

Suppose I want to make a member variable of a class a pointer to the type that will be given when the class is called. How would I go about doing this? This is what I have so far.

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
class myClass {
    T* ptr;

    public:
        myClass(int size);
};  

template <typename T>
myClass<T>::myClass(int size)
{   
    *ptr = new T(size);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    myClass<int> instance(5);
    return 0;
}
```

When I dereference the pointer in the constructor I get the following error:
`error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’`

This leads me to believe that the so called pointer variable in the class isn't being made a pointer. How can I make it a pointer to whatever type the user passes when the class is instantiated?

Comment: Change this `*ptr = new T(size);` to `ptr = new T(size);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be `ptr = new T[size]`. `new T[size]` has type `int*`.

Answer (score 3):

```
*ptr = new T(size);
```

The type of the expression `*ptr` is `T`, not `T*`.

Write this:

```
ptr = new T(size);
```

but then I guess, you don't meant that either. You *probably* meant this:

```
ptr = new T[size];
```

Know the difference between `(size)` and `[size]`.

But then if you meant `[size]`, then you should rather prefer `std::vector<T>` over `T*`

Or if you really meant `(size)`, then use `T` instead of `T*`. Or `std::unique_ptr<T>` if you *really need* pointer.

Comment: I think you meant `*ptr` is `T`, not `T*`. In both the cases you say not.

Comment: @Mahesh: Typo fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using code like this:

```
template <typename T>
myClass<T>::myClass(int size)
: ptr(new T[size])
{
}

template <typename T>
myClass<T>::~myClass()
{
   delete [] ptr;
}
```

1. You should give a value to your member "ptr", not "*ptr"
2. According to Scott Meyers' "Effective C++", using initial instead of assign.
3. Clear out in your destructor.